# How to handle new tab opening with Splash?

Tags: scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm scraping website which has a very annoying link (`<a>` HTML tag) - it opens the small pop-up form on click and after submitting it, opens new browser tab (and switches focus to it) with URL that I need, and also redirects old tab to another page.

Successful submitting of the pop-up form was easy, but I don't know how to get URL of this new tab.

And as the documentation says, Splash can work only with one tab, so is it impossible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As Splash's developer [comments](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/755#issuecomment-375069305) on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/755) this feature is not implemented.

But I posted [my solution](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/755#issuecomment-375578989) to this problem on the same issue. 
Example:

```
function main(splash, args)

  assert(splash:go(args.url))  -- execute JS code below only after loading the page

  splash:runjs("var newTabURL")
  splash:runjs("newTabURL = null")  -- sometimes JS can't find variable without this line
  splash:runjs("window.open = function(url){newTabURL = url}")

  -- actions which open the new tab

  local new_tab_url  = splash:evaljs("newTabURL")

  -- other actions
end
```